# @NonCPS stops after first build step

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In a `@NonCPS` annotated function, only code up to the very first jenkins build step is executed. Does anyone have the same problem? Am I missing something? I am using Jenkins LTS... just sayin' (2.73.2).

This is my code:

```
@NonCPS
def hello() {
    println 'Output "hello":'
    sh 'echo Hello'
    println 'Output "World":'
    sh 'echo World'
}

node {
    stage('Test') {
        hello()
    }
}
```

I would expect this code to run properly, but the output is the following:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Sandbox/pipeline-test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] echo
Output "hello":
[Pipeline] sh
[pipeline-test] Running shell script
+ echo Hello
Hello
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Not sure it's possible to run the commands in parallel using this syntax. Have you tried: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230922168-Pipeline-Parallel-execution-of-tasks ?

Comment: This issue isn't about parallelism

Comment: Yes I know that and I doubt if it's possible to run commands this way.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about your doubts? Any help appreciated. That pipeline code runs in my Jenkins, creates two stages and will execute any simple command inside that list iteration - aside from the build command.

Comment: You didn't mention that the `build` command is the only one that does not work? Is that true?

Comment: Yes! Putting a `println 1` before `build`  and `println 2` after it, only the first one is executed. Everything after `build` is not executed - but the next stage starts.

Comment: This stone age debugging isn't fun. I may figured out what causes my issues and updated the question with a very simple example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot run build steps inside `@NonCPS` methods. Pipeline scripts are considered "serializable", allowing them to be durable across system failures etc. Only a subset of the capabilities of groovy used by pipeline scripts is serializable - for anything that is not, you use `@NonCPS` to execute it.

Essentially, your `@NonCPS` method needs to do its business and return data back to the "safe", serialized execution stack.

In your particular example code I see no reason why `hello()` has to be `@NonCPS` at all - I can only assume your real function is doing something more complex.

(Edit)
Having just looked at your question history and the original script; I don't know if this is still the case with the latest versions but when I was writing our scripts ~6 months ago, `each { thing ->` iteration was not serializable.

Comment: That's why it was moved to a `@NonCPS` function and did not work as expected. Thanks, I somehow completely missed, that build steps could not be executed in those functions. Though I did write some plenty of pipeline code till today. Thanks!